# Ag-grid: make cell editing enabled/disabled dynamically (based on another field)

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in Angular, using full row editing. I want to disable editing of one of the fields based on another field, but I want the field to be disabled/enabled as soon as the other field's value changes (not once editing stops).

I have recreated my scenario here with a simple example: if the `ID` value is more than 0, enable the `Value` field, else, disable the `Value` field.

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
    templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html'
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;

    constructor() {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
          enableSorting: true,
          // enable filtering 
          enableFilter: true
        };
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: "ID",
                field: "id",
                width: 100,
                editable: true
            },
            {
                headerName: "Value",
                field: "value",
                width: 100,
                editable: true
            },

        ];
        this.gridOptions.rowData = [
            {id: 5, value: 10},
            {id: 10, value: 15},
            {id: 15, value: 20}
        ]
        this.gridOptions.rowSelection='single';
        this.gridOptions.editType='fullRow';
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-ody29i?file=app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.ts) is a SlackBlitz of my issue.

How can I achieve this? I was going down the route of using a computed to get the value of `ID` every time it changes it always gets the value saved, not the value just entered. I've also tried many of the event hooks that ag-grid provides such as `rowValueChanged` and `rowEditingStopped` but they are only called once you stop editing, not when something changes.

Comment: editable: ()=>false , so you can check previous cell and return condition here

Comment: @ABOS _I want the field to be disabled/enabled as soon as the other field's value changes (not once editing stops)_

Comment: there are many event hooks on ag grid documentation page, have you tried?

Comment: @ABOS yes I have, see updated question.

Comment: I don't see any easy way to toggle the second cell with  out of box options from ag grid. I tried grab input element from the id column and then add event listener to watch its value change. then query the row object and toggle the status of the second cell. Perhaps this can work, but a lot of work

Comment: @ABOS maybe a work around could be my best option. Could you illustrate this in a SlackBlitz?

Comment: here you are https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-picuvu, I have not put in any toggle logic since I am not familiar with it ...Good luck

Comment: an easy approach will be to create a variable of boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it like that:

```
editable: (params)=>{return params.data["id"]>0}
```

but this case wouldn't perfectly work as you might expect (editable function will be executed only on edit-start event, while editing it wouldn't track your changes)

for fully handling your requirements you have to create custom `cellEditors` for validation in 'live-time' changes

you could check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734474/4483102) to get more info about validation

Answer (score 0):

*This is a long time ago but maybe someone can still find this answer useful.*

That said, the easy approach will be to define a variable of Boolean type.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html'
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
private gridOptions: GridOptions;
isEditable: boolean = false; //<== define the variable here


constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
      enableSorting: true,
      // enable filtering 
      enableFilter: true
    };
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: "ID",
            field: "id",
            width: 100,
            editable: true,
            valueSetter: (params: any) => { // set the value here

              params.value > 0 ? this.isEditable = true : this.isEditable = false;

              // === do your actual valueSetter stuffs for this field here === //
            }
        },
        {
            headerName: "Value",
            field: "value",
            width: 100,
            editable: this.isEditable //<== pass the variable as value here
        },

    ];
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [
        {id: 5, value: 10},
        {id: 10, value: 15},
        {id: 15, value: 20}
    ]
    this.gridOptions.rowSelection='single';
    this.gridOptions.editType='fullRow';
}
```

}