# How to implement validation rules for ag-grid row edit

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-validation

I currently have html table with inline editing that uses plain Angular Reactive Forms, including a lot of validation rules:

```
var formArray = new FormArray(this.items.map(createItemFormGroup));

createItemFormGroup(item){
   return new FormGroup({
        prop1: new FormControl(item.prop1, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)])
        prop2:...
   })
}
```

Is there any example of how to integrate ag-grid with Angular validations? The requirement is, that I need to highlight invalid cell values. I don't necessarily need to use FormGroup…

I will probably use full row editing, so one way to go would be to create FormGroup only for row, that is being edited....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AG Grid: Better way for validation row - valueSetter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710350/ag-grid-better-way-for-validation-row-valuesetter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways of possible  validation handling:

First: via [`ValueSetter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/#value-setter) function

and

Second: via custom [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) component

<kbd>[**Example one**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GFgb4v7P8YCW1PxJwGTx?p=preview)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Example two**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dAAU8yLMnR8dm4vNEa9T?p=preview)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Async validation**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dAAU8yLMnR8dm4vNEa9T?p=preview)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Extended validation**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dAAU8yLMnR8dm4vNEa9T?p=preview)</kbd>