# equals function in coldef has undefined parameters

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to cancel a change of value after editing a cell. The flow is :

- finish edition ( onCellValueChanged )
- request to web service:
- if request fail cancel edition ( reverse to old value ).
- if request is ok nothing to do

Fot that I try to use the gridOptions.onCellValueChanged listener, which works but the event.newValue is the same as event.oldValue:

```
this.gridOptions.onCellValueChanged = event => {
         // Here event.newValue == event.oldValue
      }
```

The cell model is an object (not a string or a simple type ).
So I tracked down the problem to maybe the redefinition of equals within the coldef :

```
coldef: {
 /* a lot of def ...*/
 equals: function(object1, object2) {
        console.log("equal : ", object1, object2);
        return object1.Id === object2.Id;
       },
     };
```

But here ont the log object1 and object2 are undefined.
Why is that ?
And bonus question : is this the good way to cancel the change of cell data ?

Comment: question already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358430/how-to-implement-validation-rules-for-ag-grid-row-edit/55362090#55362090) few times

Comment: @un.spike thanks but still not what i am looking for ... but it made me think of the flow ... Indeed my issue is that I validate editing and then whithin the valuechanged event I do a check with web service, to be able to cancel that change at the end of this event.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a valueGetter function in colDef, equals function gets its params from valueGetter function