# How can I restrict special characters in Angular AG Grid cell?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

How can I restrict special characters in an [Angular AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/) cell?

```
columnDefs = [
  { headerName: '', width: 60, pinned: 'left', checkboxSelection: true }, 
  { headerName:'seq_no', width: 100, field: 'seqno', editable: true }, 
  { headerName: 'name', width: 100, field: 'name', editable: true, cellEditor:"numericEditor" }
]
```

I have 2 columns in AG Grid. One is a sequence number and another one is a name. I don't have any issue in the sequence number column, but now I want to restrict special characters in name column (it should allow only alphabet characters).

Is there any solution?

Comment: This thread may have your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358430/how-to-implement-validation-rules-for-ag-grid-row-edit